# axios.post with formData always return empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, form-data

**Problems**

axios.post with formData always return empty object {}

code of react app

```
const UserSignup = () => {
  
  const signupUser = async (event) => {
    try {
      event.preventDefault();
      const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('signupForm'));
      const res = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND}/users/signup`,
        formData
      );

      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>signup form</h1>
      <form onSubmit={signupUser} id="signupForm">
        email : <HTextInput name="email" />
        password :
        <HTextInput name="password" type="password" />
        passwordCheck :
        <HTextInput name="passwordCheck" type="password" />
        <Button type="submit">signup</Button>
      </form>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

**I checked..**

- *is formData key-values stored?*

yes. I checked key-values by adding some codes like

```
...
const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('signupForm'));

      // FormData key
      for (let key of formData.keys()) {
        console.log(key);
      }

      // FormData value
      for (let value of formData.values()) {
        console.log(value);
      }

      const res = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND}/users/signup`,
        formData
      );
...
```

[key-values printed in browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo1Wx.png)

- *is backend(Nest.js) working well?*

yes. I checked with postman and it works perfectly

[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0GiR.png)

[backend response(console.log(body))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rECDq.png)

waiting for some help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Test with postman

---

There's lot of body types like `form-data`, `x-www-form-urlencoded`..

I found that

- post data with `form-data` return empty `{}`

but

- post data with `x-www-form-urlencoded` return what i expected like `{ email : "aa@google.com "}`

problem was the way receiving formdata in backend(Nest.js)

### 2. use UseInterceptors

---

I add code in nest.js like

```
...

@Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file')) // <-- this
createUser(@Body body: any) {
...
```

it work well i expected whether content-type is default(`x-www-form-urlendcoed`) or `multipart/form-data` in **React application**

I can't exactly explain why this happened and work.

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `{headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }}` as a third argument to your `axios.post()` call.

Comment: I tried, but it returns same empty object `{}` anyway, thanks for your comment :)